# How do I jump to a definition (function definitions, struct definitions, ...) in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, definition

I usually use Notepad++ to read open source, but I don't know
how to jump to a definition or jump back previous position.
How do I do that?

Comment: This should be migrated to superuser

Answer (score 5):

I'm using the [SourceCookifier plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sourcecookifier/) for this. The file containing the definition must be open in N++. Going back is just CTRL+SHIFT+TAB.

Comment: `CTRL+SHIFT+TAB` switches tabs for me.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an ancient question, but Notepad++ has View -> Function List now. Doesn't work across files, but most of the other plugins I tried I had lots of problems getting working.

Answer (score 2):

TagsJump works fine: http://sourceforge.net/projects/tagsjump/

Answer (score 1):

1. Install SourceCookifier plugin from plugin manager.
2. Open the file which you want to edit.
3. Click on the function name or struct name (place the pointer in between the name)
4. Press`CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`

This will send you to the definition (or shows a drop down menu for definitions if function overloading is implemented from which you can select) .

Comment: SourceCookifier doesn't show on Plugin Manager (Notepad++ v7.7.1). Nor TagsJump btw.